# How can you check which children are active within a parent in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent, children

I have a list of cameras under a "Cameras" parent:[image]

In my game, I want to set my character's relativity to whichever camera is active. For example, if Camera012 is active, then set the character's controls to be relative to Camera012. However, I don't know how to check through a parent object to see which children are setactive or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (Camera002.activeInHierarchy) {
// do something
}
```

if you need you can add all camera to an array and use for loop to check each camera

Comment: Your answer is very close to perfect, however I would like you to clarify a bit more of what you mean by "add all camera to an array and use for loop to check each camera". :)

Comment: Do you mean something such as `GameObject[] cameras = GetComponentsInChildren<GameObject>();
        foreach (GameObject currentCam in cameras)
        {
            if (currentCam.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                camF = currentCam.transform.forward;
                camR = currentCam.transform.right;
            }
        }` ?

Comment: you can do a few different ways, you could add a ‘camera’ tag to all cameras and on Start or Awake GameObject cameras[] = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(“camera”);

Answer (score 2):

If you just ask for children which are active its easy, if you want only one child a time add a sciprt to Cameras object that include

```
Camera firstactiveCamera = GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
```

This will return only first active camera

If you want to find all active cameras in children then it turn back an array.

```
Camera[] activeCamerasInChildren = GetComponentsInChildren<Camera>();
```

Diffrence is this is plural(Components) so you get all active camera objects in children.

Even if you want inactive objects in children then you can use

```
Camera[] activeCamerasInChildren = GetComponentsInChildren<Camera>(true);
```

If you send true with function getcomponent it even find inactive objects and return them in array.

Comment: It seems that your code looks for objects in a parent that has the "Camera' component. I was asking how I could find children that have `setactive(true)`

Comment: List<GameObject> activeGameobjects = new List<GameObject>();
 
        for (int i = 0; i < gameObject.transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            if(gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.activeSelf == true)
            {
                activeGameobjects.Add(gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
            }
        }

Answer (score 2):

The drawback of `GetComponentsInChildren` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61571841/7111561)) is that it also returns eventually further nested children and does not only look through the first level children.

Also `activeInHierarchy` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61571777/7111561)) returns only `true`, if all parent in the Hierarchy of the examined object are also active.

---

In general You can iterate through all first level children of a GameObject by using

```
foreach(Transform child in someGameObject.transform)
{
    // use child
}
```

and check whether a child is active or not using

```
// the object to examine the childs of
Transform parent;

// iterate through all first level children
foreach(Transform child in parent)
{
    if(child.gameObject.activeSelf)
    {
        Debug.Log($"The child {child.name} is active!");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log($"The child {child.name} is inactive!");
    }
}
```

this works also if any parent in the objects Hierarchy is inactive but the child itself active.

Answer (score -1):

```
public GameObject gameobject_I want to know;

print(gameobject_I want to know.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().Length);
```